# Oracle ADF page life cycle and how does a validation check is performed

Tags: validation, oracle12c, oracle-adf, page-lifecycle

I am new to Oracle ADF. I am in a Page where when we have **insert new** Button, which gives a popup with new form to insert values. I have some validation in the entity level which is done using method function. I am not giving any auto submit and neither invoking the commit button. Just when I gave a press Ok button the validation is performed. That OK button is not invoking any commit. How does the entity level validation check is performed here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/web.1111/b31974/adf_lifecycle.htm#ADFFD1392 and here you get a more detailed insight https://www.ateam-oracle.com/understanding-the-jsf-lifecycle-and-adf-optimized-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Any ADF command***(Button/Link/Image/...) component with partialSubmit=false , will submit the entire the FORM data , during the FORM submission, ADF life cycle will trigger the validations.